# Dynamically added content no longer opens accordion

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an accordion that opens within a modal window. The accordion is no longer working because I'm creating the content for the modal dynamically now, where before, the data was hard coded in my HTML, so everything functioned as expected.

This is what I have now for my AJAX call:

```
      ...
      success : function(data)
      {
        $('<div/>', {
          id:'modal'
        }).html(data).appendTo('body');

        $('#modal').popup({
          autoopen  : true,
        });
      },
```

And this is the call for the accordion:

```
$('.accordion').accordion({
    collapsible: true
});
```

The modal window opens no problem, but the accordion does not collapse or open anymore. I can also see that there are no events tied to the accordion, and before the changes, there were.

Because the content for my modal is being created dynamically now, is there a way to get the accordion functioning again?

Comment: `$('.accordion').accordion("refresh");` I think this will fix it

Comment: Since the accordion is created dynamically, you will need to use event delegation. I think bootstrap might have something regarding that in the docs. Let me check.

Comment: Thanks Eddie. I added that code underneath the original call. Was this right?

Comment: Yes, both elements along with the content are all being created dynamically now.

Comment: Add that after/every time you add/edit the accordion

Comment: Eddie's comment seems to have fixed it. If you want to post your answer, Eddie, I'll be happy to credit you for the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to refresh the accordion every time you do an edit.

```
$('.accordion').accordion("refresh");
```

Comment: Thanks Eddie. I'm now having another issue. Now that the accordion is working again, the dynamically added content is showing the same data for all the elements, which is not right. It looks like the data is being cached, but I've added `cache:false` to the AJAX call and it still shows the same dataset. If I post a new answer, can you have a look?

Comment: Yeah, I can check.

Comment: Thank you, Eddie. I'm posting it now.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because when you do $('.accordion').accordion({..., you don't have ".accordion" class, because AJAX is not done yet, and you set up accordion on on non existing class. It's similar with click events in jquery. Quick workaround for this is to setup your accordion in "success" function of AJAX. Like this:

```
success : function(data)
  {
    $('<div/>', {
      id:'modal'
    }).html(data).appendTo('body');

    $('.accordion').accordion({
        collapsible: true
    });

    $('#modal').popup({
      autoopen  : true,
    });
  },
```

Or like Eddie said, you can use $('.accordion').accordion("refresh");, Like this:

```
success : function(data)
    {
        $('<div/>', {
            id:'modal'
        }).html(data).appendTo('body');

        $('.accordion').accordion("refresh");
        $('#modal').popup({
            autoopen  : true,
        });
    },
```

And it's important to put it after html(data).appendTo('body');. I hope I helped to understand the problem.

Comment: Thank you, Ivan for the detailed explanation. It's helpful indeed. I did exactly what you posted after I saw that the refresh Eddie suggested worked.

Comment: I'm having a different issue now, so I'm going to post a new question. Hopefully you will be available to have a look at it.