# AJAX appears to be caching my results

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is a stub from another post located here: [Dynamically added content no longer opens accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47568642/dynamically-added-content-no-longer-opens-accordion#47568768)

The issue I am having is that my database result set appears to be cached in JQuery. I have added `cache:false` to the AJAX call but the results appear the same for any element I click on which is not correct. Every element has it's own ID and will return a different result set. I'm not sure why this is happening, but is there something that I am missing, or something else that I can check?

This is the AJAX call so far:

```
  ...
  success : function(data)
  {
    $('<div/>', {
      id:'modal'
    }).html(data).appendTo('body');

    $('#modal').popup({
      autoopen  : true,
    });

    $('.accordion').accordion({
        collapsible: true,
    });
  },
```

Basically, `data` carries the results being returned from my database. I have checked the results in Firebug and can see each element has the right data, but it's not rendering that way.

EDIT:

```
$.ajax({
url  : "modal.asp",
type : "POST",
cache: false,
data : $(this).data('cid'),
success : function(data)
{
  $('<div/>', {
    id:'modal'
  }).html(data).appendTo('body');

  $('#modal').popup({
    autoopen  : true,
  });

  $('.accordion').accordion({
    collapsible: true,
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you post full ajax?

Comment: You set the same id every time, so not sure what you mean by "every element has [its] own id".

Comment: Sure, Ivan. I'll do it now

Comment: `modal` is the ID of the updates all the time

Comment: @JJJ and @Eddie, no, I mean the `data('cid')` for my database. This is the ID I am using to differentiate between the data. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Clear your browser cache data and test again.

Comment: No idea what that means, but you still set the HTML element's id the same. Ids must be unique. `$('#modal')` always refers to the first element with that id on the page, which is why you always see the first data, regardless of what the Ajax call returns.

Comment: We are talking about this code `$('<div/>', {id:'modal' })`

Comment: I think I see where is the problem. Try to add $("#modal").remove(); on top of success function of ajax and post the result.

Comment: I think you have to destroy the modal after closing it, otherwise your code `$('<div/>', {id:'modal' })` will create a new element and call the first `<div id="modal">`

Comment: I think Ivan is right here.. Also, MAZux.. I think I need to destroy the modal so that it will reload the new data. Ivan, when you say on top of success function, you mean outside the AJAX function?

Comment: Uh... no. It's the duplicate ids, trust me.

Comment: Like this: success : function(data){ $("#modal").remove(); ...

Comment: @JJJ, okay, you are probably right, but how then do I add dynamic content to a single modal? Also, if the element is destroyed, it should be recreated and all should be fine. Am I wrong?

Comment: Just chain the methods, no need for ids at all. `$('<div/>').html(data).appendTo('body').popup({autoopen: true});`

Comment: @IvanGajic, I tried that and what happens is that the modal opens once and then after it's removed, I get nothing... no modal, just the black background

Comment: You have multi div with the same id you have to remove the div after closing the modal.

Comment: One question, are you replacing or appending data on the accordion? Can you post your html for the accordion?

Comment: @Eddie, the data is all being compiled on the backend, dynamically, when the user clicks on the element.

Comment: I love it when people know what the hell they're talking about. :)  JJJ is right. I'm no JS expert, but the method chaining example is now giving me the right results. JJJ, if you want to post the answer, I'd be happy to credit you for it. Also, can you please explain why your example works? I don't see what's different about method chaining over what I had there originally.

Comment: OK, gotcha, thanks. It's makes sense. Here's the thing now... Because there is no id for the div element, my styles are no longer applied. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Nan Add a class instead

Comment: @Eddie, I've changed all of the ID instances in the CSS, but now the accordion stopped working. I think the plugin is looking for an ID, but that's just me speculating. Is there a way to use an ID and destroy it after the modal closes?

Comment: Instead of creating a modal every time you request an ajax. Cant you just reuse / update the existing modal? So create 1 modal and change/update the content everytime ajax.

Comment: @Eddie, this is what I originally had. I built the data on the backend and then inserted it into my document. So, what I had was one modal/accordion for all the elements on the page. This seemed like the better way to handle it, but the issue I was running into was that whatever changes I made to one element was also showing for all the other elements on the page. This was why I thought building the data as the user requested it was the only way to get it working. Also, the problem with building one modal for the entire page was that I didn't have access to a needed database ID, now I do.

Comment: I added an answer. I am not sure if this is how you want it. Just let me know if it works or not. @NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
        url  : "modal.asp",
        type : "POST",
        cache: false,
        data : $(this).data('cid'),
    success : function(data)
    {
        var newData = "<div>" + data + "</div>";
        $('.accordion').html(newData)
        $('.accordion').accordion("refresh");    

        $('#modal').modal('show');      
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Eddie. I just got it working. Here's what I did. I looked at the callback events for the modal and saw an onclose event, so I `remove` the `#modal` in that event function and it works as expected now.

Comment: Wow. Thats great!

Comment: It sure is! Man, AJAX is sure cool, but it can also be a huge PITA sometimes, especially when I'm not real savoy with it. Thank you again for all your help! You really helped me a lot, as did the rest of the guys here!

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that I decided to forgo building the modal on the backend as you suggested, and hard coded it back into my document. I'm using JQuery to find and change the selectors from there. This is the correct way of doing it I believe. I got to thinking about it after you asked me why I wasn't doing it that way in the first place. Thank you, Eddie!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not removing your old #modal div(s), therefore they accumulate.

Multiple DOM elements with same id are invalid HTML and the effect of selecting `$('#modal)` is indeterminate. It's probably selecting the first one ... repeatedly

Comment: Now that everyone mentions it, I can see that this is exactly right. Eddie suggested removing the element which, by my calculations, should have fixed it, but it still wasn't working. Why is this?

Comment: Yes that should fix it. Alternatively, reuse the same div over and over.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
$('<div/>', {
    id:'modal'
    }).html(data).appendTo('body');
```

Will create a new `div` element with an id of `modal`.

```
$('div#modal').html(data).appendTo('body');
```

This would modify your modal content.

If your element doesn't exist at first call, just do this:

```
if($('div#modal').length > 0){
    $('div#modal').html(data).appendTo('body');
} else {
    $('<div/>', {
        id:'modal'
       }).html(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks MAZux. I'll give this a try for fun and see what I get.

Comment: Mazuz, this does nothing at all. I don't get any errors, but the modal never opens.